# How to map dataset parameter to report parameter in SSRS - Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I created a dataset with a parameter ( the parameter is automatically created ), and I created a parameter in the report. How can I associate the two so that when I run the report the parameter prompted passes the value to the datasets parameter? In MSDN, there`s a dataset properties -> parameter where you can pass the name and value, but all Ive got in that window is the name and *default* value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the dataset that you want to pass the parameter to, select `Dataset properties` and select `Parameters` and you will get a screen showing the mapped parameters. Use this screen to map any parameters that are missing and pass them values.

Normally when you put a parameter into your query then the parameter gets added to the report parameters and the mapped parameters for that dataset automatically.